# What is PSS waveform formula?

Tags: telecommunication, lte, modulation

I want to know how is exactly modulated a LTE subcarrier.

Since I'm working on Synchronization Signals (P-SS, S-SS) the subcarriers I'm talking about are centered around DC.

I have coded the algorithms that output diverse information (Zadoff-Chu sequences, m-sequences...) that will be carried by the specific 62 subcarriers (1.4MHz BW) corresponding to both PSCH and SSCH.

I'm now willing to modulate the information on the subcarriers.

My guess is that this formula is some kind of sinusoidal signal, i.e. for PSS:
s(t) = sin(2π*k*Fe/f + φ) factor the data I want to map on.

I've found what seems to be the general equation of the subcarrier, s(t)=A(t)exp(|wt + phi(t)|) giving a classic s(t)=A(t)cos(wt + Phi(t))

But I haven't found anything precise until now on OFDM documentation about the complete modulation.